# EF7 (beta 7) - What's the correct way to join many-to-many tables and return data to AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am having a bit of trouble getting this to work. I started with a working App:
I have a "Companies" table, that has a many-to-many relationship with another table "Groups".

when the get is:

```
 // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Company> Get()
    {           
       return _dbContext.Companies;
    }
```

it all works and i get all 3 records back.
but if i change the implementation to include some logic, mainly checking for the logged in user id and getting just the items related to him, i am getting nothing back to angular.
this is the code:

```
// GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Company> Get()
    {
        string userId = User.GetUserId();
        var thisUserAndGroups = _dbContext.Users.Where(y => y.Id == userId).Include(x => x.UserGroups).ToList();

        List<int> groupIDs = new List<int>();
        foreach (UserGroups i in thisUserAndGroups.First().UserGroups)
        {
            groupIDs.Add(i.GroupId);
        }

        var GroupsAndCompanies = _dbContext.Groups.Include(x => x.GroupCompanies).Where(a => groupIDs.Contains(a.GroupId)).ToList();

        List<int> companyIDs = new List<int>();

        foreach (Group g in GroupsAndCompanies)
        {
            foreach (GroupCompanies gc in g.GroupCompanies)
            {
                companyIDs.Add(gc.CompanyId);
            }
        }



        IEnumerable<Company> ret = _dbContext.Companies.Where(b => companyIDs.Contains(b.CompanyId)).ToList();
        return ret;

    }
```

when i debug this, and put my breakpoint in the "return ret" line, it does have the correct data.
my theory says that the "Company" is extended because of the "Include" command and the JSONization can't "eat it" so it comes back empty.
am I right? how do I get it to work?

just to be clear my Company model is:

```
 public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        InfoTabs = new List<InfoTab>();
        GroupCompanies = new HashSet<GroupCompanies>();
    }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InfoTab> InfoTabs { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<GroupCompanies> GroupCompanies { get; set; }
}
```

Group:

```
 public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string AccessLevelIT { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string AccessLevelTicketing { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GroupCompanies> GroupCompanies { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserGroups> UserGroups { get; set; }

    public Group()
    {
        GroupCompanies = new HashSet<GroupCompanies>();
        UserGroups = new HashSet<UserGroups>();
    }

}
```

GroupCompanies (many-to-many):

```
    public class GroupCompanies
{       
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

UserGroups (many-to-many):

```
  public class UserGroups
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }


}
```

and finally, Users is .net's Identity table untouched. just added this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<UserGroups> UserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

}

**EDIT** 
As I suspected and as was confirmed by @jpgrassi, the problem WAS that the use of "include" created an object that the JSONization couldn't handle.
for the moment I added code to bypass the problem:

```
 List<Company> retCollection = new List<Company>();
        foreach (Company c in ret)
        {
            Company inner = new Company();
            inner.CompanyId = c.CompanyId;
            inner.CompanyName = c.CompanyName;
            retCollection.Add(inner);
        }
        return retCollection;
```

essentially coping the data to non-expanded Company items. 
**however i know this sucks. please help me get this code written better! i am sure this is not the way to do it.**

thanks for your help!

Comment: You could do with creating some Join queries in your company, I can help but at a high level what data are you trying to get from the `Get()`

Comment: I suspect you are in the right "track". I recommend you not return directly you entity to your view, instead, create a DTO or something. It has the advantage of being more lightweight to carry around. Also, I recommend you to encapsulate your queries in a Repository/Business and in your controller just call your business. That way you can reduce drastically your app's dependency.

Comment: @CallumLinington well this is the structure: main objects are company, group, user. they are all connected via many-to many so the order is : 1.company   2. GroupCompanies   3. group   4. UserGroups   5. users.  i have "userID" that is present in 4,5 above and need to get all companies that are in groups that are associated with the user.

Comment: @jpgrassi - returning a DTO is OK, but how do i do it? my angularJS controller Ienumerable so DTO will work.

Comment: As Callum said, it's hard to achieve without knowing what is it you need to return in your get method. Is it a list of companies by user? try to explain more... also, you should do it in only one query. Use joins, there's tons of examples online.

Comment: You may also need to list out the entities information, so I can see where the joins can happen.

Comment: @CallumLinington i edited the question and added all the entity info. thanks for your help by the way - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So my initial go is this:

```
var userId = "";

var foundCompanies = userGroups
                    .Where(x => x.ApplicationUserId == userId)
                    .Join(groupCompanies,
                            ug => ug.GroupId,
                            gc => gc.GroupId,
                            (userGroup, groupCompany) => new { groupCompany.Company })
                    .ToList();

// so the above statement will get back back a UserGroup and a GroupCompanies where their GroupId match.
```

Because you have those joining tables it makes doing these joins so much easier. With no need to go through those navigation properties (which I personally hate).

With the join, you have to return back an anonymous object because it's being translated to SQL.

`(userGroup, groupCompany) => new { groupCompany.CompanyId })`

This line is a `Select` line basically. It's defining how you want to project the relationship between these two entities. All I care about is the company. But you could return the `ApplicationUser` and the `Company`, then do group by to make distinct result sets.

Comment: my UserGroups and GroupCompanies tables were not in the dbcontext, but when i do add them i cannot use them as the other tables - they have odd methods and properties. i think it is related to how EF7 does the many-to-many. any other idea using navigational properties?

Comment: i tried everything i could and i couldn't make this code work for me (see my first comment here)

Comment: @tarkil oh right, I didn't realise they weren't in you db context, this won't work for that. Are you doing code first or database first?

Comment: Code first. The models used are in the question.

Comment: I know your models are, but your dbcontext isn't which tells me what tables you have exposed. If you show your dbcontext I will be able to guide better

Comment: I have companies, groups, users. Sorry not at the computer to paste it.

Comment: My code is really bothering me as it seems poorly written. Can anyone help? This is crucial to my understanding of querying non 'just get all' queries.